# JAVA Reference to object form class A in other class

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I have a class:

```
public class RectangularSection {

public double widthRectangle;

public double getWidthRectangle() {
    return widthRectangle;
}

public void setWidthRectangle(double widthRectangle) {
    this.widthRectangle = widthRectangle;
}}
```

And class with object "section":

```
public class RectangleController implements Initializable {

RectangularSection section = new RectangularSection();

public RectangularSection getObject(){
    return section;
}

public void setRectangularSection(RectangularSection obj){
    this.section = obj;
}

@FXML
private TextField widthRectangle;

public TextField getWidthRectangle() {
    return widthRectangle;
}

public void setWidthRectangle(TextField widthRectangle) {
    this.widthRectangle = widthRectangle;
}

@Override
public void initialize(URL arg0, ResourceBundle arg1) {
}}
```

And I need object "section" from RectangleController in this class

```
public class Controller implements Initializable  {

RectangularSection section = new RectangularSection();
RectangleController object2 = new RectangleController();

@FXML
private Label szer;

    @FXML
private void sendStrengthClassOfConcrete() {
    object2.setRectangularSection(section);
    object2.section.setWidthRectangle(Double.parseDouble(object2.getWidthRectangle().getText()));
    szerokosc.setText(String.valueOf(object2.getObjekt().getWidthRectangle()));


}}
```

I read about this and I did the same but it doesen't work What am I doing wrong ?
.......................................................................

Comment: can you put the generated exception?

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at application.Controller.sendStrengthClassOfConcrete(Controller.java:97)
 ... 61 more

Comment: exception in line: object2.section.setWidthRectangle(Double.parseDouble(object2.getWidthRectangle().getText()));

Comment: when I do static object, all is well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is lot of scope of code improvement, but I will not restructure the code all through.

For your defect, you are not setting the `widthRectangle` field and you are trying to get it via `.getWidthRectangle().getText()` which is throwing `NullPointerException`

To Solve it, set the `widthRectangle` value before you use it in `sendStrengthClassOfConcrete()` method.

```
private void sendStrengthClassOfConcrete() {
        object2.setRectangularSection(section);
        TextField someNumberTextField = new TextField("24");
        object2.setWidthRectangle(someNumberTextField);
        object2.section.setWidthRectangle(Double.parseDouble(object2
                .getWidthRectangle().getText()));
```